# Cannot connect to a port from outside even if Windows Firewall is OFF

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, port

I'm getting a strange problem in my Windows 2008 R2 server running on a Hyper-V Virtual Machine. My application is listening to port `8002`, which is well listed in command: `netstat -na`

Now I'm able to telnet to the same port (`8002`) from the same system, but I could not Telnet to this port from another system in the same VLAN. I'm able to Telnet port `135` of the server from another system, but not to this port (`8002`). I had turned off the Windows Firewall, enabled logging, allowed all traffic etc, but there was no sign of the connection from outside system.

Even I checked to Telnet to some other ports, and to my surporise, some of the connected but some didn't. Also, I run the same application in different system, it got connected from outside. Hence, I deduce that this is not the problem with the application. Please help.

EDIT: The system (both Windows 2008 r2 & Hyper-V) is a newly installed one.

RESOLVED: This issue is resolved, after we have found that, the antivirus client installed at  the Hyper-V hypervisor (not the windows VM) is blocking the connection! Still don't know,why it is happening to this AV client only! Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Try turning the firewall back on and creating an inbound rule for your port and try again.

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question.  We prefer that you add it as an answer, and accept it, to make it easier for any future readers. Self-answering id acceptable, and even encouraged around here.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the server is listening to the correct ip address (either the one you expect or 0.0.0.0).

When running `netstat -an` it will show you the local address.

Comment: I'm getting server is listening to the port (8002) of 0.0.0.0 and I can telnet to the port from the same system using: `telnet <ipaddress> <port>`

But when i do the same from other systems in the VLAN, it is not getting connected!